# iOS Simulator on Mac doesn't show Email or ActiveSync options

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator

I'm trying to test email access in the iPhone iPad simulator and there doesn't appear to be a way to use "email" POP3 or Activesync from the SDK's simulator.

How do I configure the Simulator for email access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The simulator is not meant to be a full-featured reproduction of a real iPhone or iPod Touch, hence the name "simulator" instead of "emulator". That's one of the missing features.

Answer (score 4):

The iOS email app does not exist inside the simulator. The only system apps are the web browser (for testing websites) and the address book/photo app (for inserting content into those databases, so you can access it in apps you're writing).

You will need to test these things on an iPhone or iPod Touch or iPad.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageUI` API will work on the simulator.  Here's a tutorial:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/

Comment: MessageUI only allows a user to compose an email. @makerofthings7 specifically mentioned POP3, which is only used for downloading email. So MessageUI probably isn't what he's looking for.